# Trim String Characters in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

Suppose if I have dataframe in which I have the values in a column like :

```
ABC00909083888
ABC93890380380
XYZ7394949
XYZ3898302
PQR3799_ABZ
MGE8983_ABZ
```

I want to trim these values like, remove first 3 characters and remove last 3 characters if it ends with ABZ.

```
00909083888
93890380380
7394949
3898302
3799
8983
```

Tried some methods but did not work.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

new_df = df.withColumn("new_column", f.when((condition on some column),
                                               f.substring('Existing_COL', 4, f.length(f.col("Existing_COL"))), ))
```

Can anyone please tell me which function I can use in pyspark.
Trim only removes white space or tab something characters.

Comment: When you say remove first 3 characters, does that mean you want remove everything regardless of what it starts with ?

Comment: Also, please add your expected output just to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Yes you are right.. Always remove first three characters..
Because I dont want to hard code like if it starts with ABC, XYZ, PQR .. so a general function i was looking for in pyspark to replace first three characters with "" say..

Comment: Is this scenario possible.. if the value ABC0087676 , after trimming becomes 0087676.. Then only write it is 87676..  opening the output in excel may look like 87676 only though... but just incase if it is zero.. and i want to see simply in some other format file, say text file opened with notepad

Comment: Sure. Thank you so much. WIll check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your input and expected output. See below logic -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame(data = [("ABC00909083888",) ,("ABC93890380380",) ,("XYZ7394949",) ,("XYZ3898302",) ,("PQR3799_ABZ",) ,("MGE8983_ABZ",)], schema = ["values",])

(df.withColumn("new_vals", when(col('values').rlike("(_ABZ$)"), regexp_replace(col('values'),r'(_ABZ$)', '')).otherwise(col('values')))
  .withColumn("final_vals", expr(("substring(new_vals, 4 ,length(new_vals))")))
).show()
```

**Output**

```
+--------------+--------------+-----------+
|        values|      new_vals| final_vals|
+--------------+--------------+-----------+
|ABC00909083888|ABC00909083888|00909083888|
|ABC93890380380|ABC93890380380|93890380380|
|    XYZ7394949|    XYZ7394949|    7394949|
|    XYZ3898302|    XYZ3898302|    3898302|
|   PQR3799_ABZ|       PQR3799|       3799|
|   MGE8983_ABZ|       MGE8983|       8983|
+--------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly and if you don't insist on using pyspark substring or trim functions, you can easily define a function to do what you want and then make use of that with [`udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html)s in spark:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf


def mysub(word):
  if word.endswith('_ABZ'):
    word = word[:-4]
  return word[3:]


udf1 = udf(lambda x: mysub(x), StringType())
df.withColumn('new_label',udf1('label')).show()
```

The output will be like:

```
+---+--------------+-----------+
| id|         label|  new_label|
+---+--------------+-----------+
|  1|ABC00909083888|00909083888|
|  2|ABC93890380380|93890380380|
|  3|    XYZ7394949|    7394949|
|  4|    XYZ3898302|    3898302|
|  5|   PQR3799_ABZ|       3799|
|  6|   MGE8983_ABZ|       8983|
+---+--------------+-----------+
```

Please let me know if I got you wrong in some cases.